# Oracle Dense Rank

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

I have a requirement to delete duplicate rows based on ID and times column.I need to keep records with latest times only.If there are two records with max times,I can keep anyone of the record and delete all other records within that group.Please find my input data below

```
ID  TIMES
123 13/01/2018
123 14/01/2018
123 15/01/2018
345 14/01/2018
567 20/01/2018
567 20/01/2018
879 NULL
879 21/01/2018
```

I have written a query for the same.But its not working with the case of ID=567 as both of them have same value in times column. Please find my query below

```
delete FROM table where (ID,times) in( 
  SELECT ID,times, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY times DESC NULLS LAST) dest_rank
    FROM TABLE 
  ) WHERE dest_rank <> 1
```

Is there any way I can achieve this.

Comment: You can fix your solution easily - which is no worse that the Accepted Answer. The issue is that you used the `RANK()` function. You should use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function instead. As you found out, the `RANK()` function will show ties with the same rank, so that doesn't help you. In the case of ties, `ROW_NUMBER()` will arbitrarily assign DIFFERENT numbers to the rows, and that's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
delete t from t
    where rowid <> (select max(rowid) keep (dense_rank first order by times desc)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.id = t.id
                   );
```

However, I would do this with a temporary table:

```
create temporary table tt
    select id, max(times) as times
    from t
    group by id;

truncate table t;

insert into t(id, times)
    select id, times
    from tt;
```

Comment: I think we need to use rowid<>, instead of rowid=

Comment: @GIN . . . Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

you may succeed by the contrubution or `rowid` :

```
delete mytable where (rowid) in
(
  select t1.rowid from mytable t1
   where times <
  (
  select max(times)
    from mytable t2
   where t2.id = t1.id  
     and t2.times != t1.times -- for non-matching records of times
  )
  union all
  select t1.rowid from mytable t1
   where rowid <
  (
  select max(rowid)
    from mytable t2
   where t2.id = t1.id
     and t2.times = t1.times  -- for matching records of times
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just

```
delete demo where rowid in
( select lag(rowid) over (partition by id order by times nulls first) from demo  );
```

You didn't say how you wanted the null value to be treated. Change `nulls first` to `nulls last` if you want to retain the row with a null date.